# Boolean Algebra : proving $ a + b (c + a') = a + b $

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to prove that $ a + b (c + a') = a + b  $? ($a'$ is not $a$)

I can see that this expression is valid by using a truth table, but I would like to prove it by using only algebra expressions. Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice these rules (or identities) 
$$1+X = 1, \qquad X + YX = (1+Y)X = X, \qquad  X+X' = 1$$

Then 
\begin{align}a + b(a'+c) &= (a + ba) + b(a'+c)\\ &= a+b(a+a'+c) \\&= a+b\end{align}

Comment: Can you move from a+b(c+a′) to a+b(a+a′+c) by adding a just like that?

Comment: Yes, because $a = a+ba$ as noted!

Comment: sorry I still dont see how you went from a+b(c+a′) to a+b(a+a′+c). Is there a step or two you could add to illustrate the transition?

Comment: OK, edited. You just substitute $a$ with $a+ba$, so that you get $a + ba + ba' + bc$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit your answer. It's clearer to me now.